# PIL.ImageTk module has no attribute PhotoImage

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to fetch a image from File explorer and display it using Tkinter GUI.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


root= Tk()
root.title('Browse and open images')

root.filename= filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='C:/Users/shruti and rahul/Desktop/Gloify/Projects/E-commerce Chatbot -Only python/Revant/static/uploads',
                                              title='Select a File', filetypes=(('jfif files','*.jfif'),('All files','*.*')))
my_image= ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(root.filename))
my_image_label= Label(image= my_image).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "random.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageTk.py", line 31, in <module>
    from . import Image
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 36, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tempfile.py", line 45, in <module>
    from random import Random as _Random
  File "C:\Users\shruti and rahul\Desktop\Gloify\Projects\E-commerce Chatbot -Only python\random.py", line 11, in <module>
    my_image= ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(root.filename))
AttributeError: module 'PIL.ImageTk' has no attribute 'PhotoImage'
```

Can anyone please help me solve this?

Comment: Rename `random.py` in your project to other name as `random` is a standard module of Python.

Comment: Thank you so much @acw1668. I am almost tearing up. It was utter stupidity on my part.